# HTML, How can i fit webpage into screen?

Tags: android, html, webview, screen

I'm developing application for android. my application has very big size (APKfile) that is because of some high quality images. I decided to move it into server and in app, just load the webpage and show it in through webpage. Each HTML page has just one image (without text and other items) and all images have 450 pixels width while height may be different for each image. When i load the web page, image is not fit to screen and is bigger than my screen. I need to have image fit to screen.

I know i can load just image from server but when i did it the aspect ratio was not fine and image squashed. its width stretched while the height didn't take effect. The code that i used was `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

because of some reasons I don't want change the code totally and i prefer to find a way to apply changes to html file. My html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Team Championship</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <img align="left" alt="Team Championship" src="../image/team_championship.png"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

please tell me, how it is possible to have image fit to screen in all devices?
sorry, although i'm not bad in Android programming, I'm not familiar with web programming. 
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the image to be stretched/squashed, use `CENTER_INSIDE` for `scaleType`. `FITXY` will just make the image the same size as the container, which doesn't work if they have different aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys,

but easier and fastest way is changing above image code to this:

```
<img align="left" alt="Abudhabi" src="../image/track_abudhabi.png" width="100%"/>
```

now in all devices the image is fit to screen.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a mobile website.  The test devices were an iPod Touch, and two Android phones.  No issues with the iPod Touch, but the Android phones insisted on making the image be the full size.  So you could only ever see about 25% of the image.  I searched on "fit web page with graphic to device" and it lead me here.

The adding of width="100%" worked exactly as I needed for my issue.  Simple!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions of your image, you can set the scale for your web view, e.g.:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int imgWidth = ...;
int imgHeight = ...;

if(imgWidth > displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
    int scaleInPercent = 100 * displayMetrics.widthPixels / imgWidth;
    m_webView.setInitialScale(scaleInPercent);
}
```

Just add the check for the height and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WebView, the best and simplest way is to add a style tag inside the head tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
             img{
                max-width:100%;
                height:auto;
                display:block;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
             }
        </style>  
        <title>Team Championship</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <img align="left" alt="Team Championship" src="../image/team_championship.png"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Like this, ALL THE IMAGES are fit and centered.